# What happened to my comments on this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, comments, deleted-comments

I asked [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/68925/how-were-us-progressives-able-to-deny-israel-a-billion-dollars-of-finding-for-th) question. And I then replied to Pete W's comment. This has now vanished - why?

Answer (score 6):

I deleted some comments on that question, because they did not fulfill [the purposes outlined in the description of the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Remember that comments are for discussing how the question/answer itself can be improved or to add relevant information. They are not for debates about the subject matter of the question.

Comment: @Phillip: In which case you should also delete the comment by Pete W, as he was **discussing** the content of the post and not the question at hand. As it is, it rather looks like double standards to me. I also think when a comment is deleted by a mod, some reason should be left by the mod. Otherwise it just looks rather arbitrary.

Comment: Personally, I think my comment was **adding relevant information**, such as that such a policy move showed that the Palestinian rights movement was going from strength to strength.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Your personal opinion regarding what's an encouraging sign for whom is not relevant information.

Comment: @Phillip: It's not personal opinion - Mondoweiss - which is an online publication dedicated to Palestinian advocacy pointed this out. I didn't bother including that supporting information.

Comment: @Phillip: ... because it was just a comment.